# How could chartjs font family display everywhere

Tags: javascript, chart.js

In my chartjs, I have generated a bar chart that includes a font-family like

```
title: {
  text: "Hi",
  fontSize: 24, 
  fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
},
```

I do not whether this font will display everywhere whether who receives my file.
Since I have downloaded Montserrat on my local computer and i am figuring how to include the source of the font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to provide the font in one way or the other, if your users don't have it installed locally. For example, you can embed   `Montserrat` using the Google Fonts API and use it with Chart.js as shown in the following example.

```js
Chart.defaults.font.family = 'Montserrat';
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            y: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.4.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

It looks like there are two open issues with [Missing Fonts](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/3318) and [Loading Fonts](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/8020), as documented in the [Chart.js documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/fonts.html), so you might also want to take a look at those.

Comment: May I ask why <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.4.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script> is needed?

Comment: @MoJiebu, that is simply for the example to work, it loads Chart.js from a CDN, if you already are loading it from somewhere else, you won't need this line.